# Database: Table isn't appearing under tables folder

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I am trying to create a table within the tables folder of a new database. When I create the table and put in the files and save it there is no record of it in the tables folder. It also asks me to save it again if I try to close it (even though I just saved it before). Anyone else ever had this issue? I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: have to tried restarting your visual studio?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that.

Comment: even refreshing the server wont be working ?

Comment: Na there is no record of the table. It's weird.

Comment: I can't find the .mdf file anywhere in file explorer either.

Comment: if you help with a screen shot

Comment: you probably need to install SQL Server Data Tools from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 . Try this out and let me know

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/vuk40or3h/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52571/discussion-between-krunal-patil-and-matt)